# Html in iframe works everywhere except Opera

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe:

```
<iframe id='adsFrame_11'marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

And after i load documen i want to insert html in this iframe with this code:

```
function proxyAds(n,id,src){
    var doc;
    try{
        if(document.all && !window.opera){
            doc = window.frames['adsFrame_'+id].document;
        }else if(document.getElementById){
            doc = document.getElementById('adsFrame_'+id).contentDocument;
        }
    }catch(e){
        if(console) console.warn(e);
    }

    if(doc){

        s = '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="'+src+'"></scr'+'ipt>';
        doc.open()
        doc.write(s);
        doc.close()

        $('#adsFrame_'+id).show();

    }else{
        setTimeout('proxyAds('+(++n)+','+id+',"'+src+'");', 100);
    }


}
```

This function works fine exept Opera. Opera throws exeption:

```
Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Security error: attempted to read protected variable: open
```

What's the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `src` attribute to the `<iframe/>`?

The problem probably is that Opera thinks that the iframe you've inserted is a cross-domain document. Setting a local src (for e.g. an empty HTML document) could solve the problem.

For example, you'll need a `blank.html` file, with the following content:

```
<html><body></body></html>
```

And then you can insert the iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="blank.html" id='adsFrame_11' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Comment: You mean not empty `src`? I tried to insert an empty src but magic didn't happen.